# Is using parameter names that differ from type names only by casing considered a bad practice in C#?

Tags: coding-standards, methods, parameters

I see questions similar to this with regards to parameter names that match properties on the class, but I can't find anything regarding using a parameter name that is the same as the parameter type name except for casing in C#. It doesn't seem to be a violation that I can find, but is it considered bad practice? For example, I have the following method

```
public Range PadRange(Range range) {}
```

This method takes a range, and returns a new range that has had some padding applied. So, given the generic context, I can't think of a more descriptive name for the parameter. However, I'm reminded of a a tip I picked up when reading Code Complete about "psychological distance". It says

> Psychological distance can be defined as the ease in which two items can be differentiated...As you debug, be ready for the problems caused by insufficient psychological distance between similar variable names and between similar routine names. As you construct code, choose names with large differences so that you can avoid the problem.

My method signature has a lot of "Range" going on, so it feels like it may be an issue with regards to this psychological distance. Now, I see many developers do the following

```
public Range PadRange(Range myRange) {}
```

I personally have a strong distaste for this convention. Adding a "my" prefix to variable names provides no additional context.

I also see the following

```
public Range PadRange(Range rangeToPad) {}
```

I like this better than the "my" prefixing, but still don't care for it overall. It just feels overly verbose to me, and reads awkwardly as a variable name. To me, it's understood that range will be padded because of the method name.

So with all this laid out, my gut is to go with the first signature. To me, it's clean. No need to force context when it's not needed. But am I doing myself or future developers a disservice with this convention? Am I violating a best practice?

Comment: If you can't come up with a more descriptive parameter, `Range range` is fine.

Comment: Choosing good names is sometimes hard.  Err on the side of verbosity, as in your last.

Comment: In this situation, the IDE will color 'Range' and 'range' differently so it's really easy to see that one is the type and one is a variable name.

Comment: It seems like there was a recommended coding practice by Microsoft to name properties exactly the same, *even with the same case*, as in `public Range Range { get; set; }`.

Comment: Yeah, I recall that. It's in their design guidelines as a consideration. "CONSIDER giving a property the same name as its type."

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members

Comment: This practice gives the reader no information about the purpose of the variable except the type and context. If the meaning of the range is obvious given the type and context, such as when passed to a `getMidpoint` function, then go ahead and call it `range`. But if the range serves a specific purpose not obviously inferred by its type and context, for example the "sensor measurement", then call it `sensorMeasurement`.

Comment: Also fine: `Range r` (at least for a short method body) and `Range toPad`.

Comment: In fact, this type of practice is encouraged.

Comment: I always considered the "my" prefix as something that is done in example code where its used to indicate to the reader that a name should be changed to something else depending on the context. It not something that should actually end up in any real code.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret Keep in mind that this isn't about a _variable_, but a _parameter_. While that might sound nitpicky, it's exactly this difference which is important here. You might use it to pad a `Range` of sensor measurements _now_, but as per OP's description, all that is important for this method is that you give it a `Range`. If you name the parameter accordingly, it will not be confusing later to reuse it for a `Range` of green unicorns. Now, if we're talking about _the variable that you pass to this method_, that's where I 100% support your statement.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that it might not give a lot of context in many cases; but sometimes, depending on the type name and whether there is only one property of the same type, the type name alone might give away the context.  It just kind of depends on the situation.

Comment: The real question is whether it is bad style to write `class t { } class Program { void t(t t) {} }`.

Comment: @Kapep I thought that too, but I actually see the "my" prefix in production code often.

Comment: Using single-letter names like `Range r` is not a good idea IMHO. The caller would often need to rely on the type name to infer the purpose of the parameter. This could be problematic as (1) types can be renamed in a way that makes the purpose of the parameter less obvious, and (2) in some contexts (e.g. method call autocomplete in some IDEs), the type information might be missing or invisible, while parameter names are usually retained. The single-letter approach is especially troublesome in heavily overloaded methods.

Comment: Related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134321/is-it-a-good-practice-to-name-the-returned-variable-result

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Don't overthink this, `Range range` is fine. I use such kind of naming for more than 15 years in C#, and probably much longer in C++, and have never experienced any real drawbacks from it, quite the opposite.

Of course, when you have different local variables in the same scope, all of the same type, it will probably help to invest some mental effort to distinguish them properly.

Comment: Another exception I'd add is when the instance is having a particular action done on it. There's a bit of room for being more descriptive as to why the parameter is needed for example.

Wack(Bozo bozoToBeWacked)

Even more so if the parameter is optional and describing what the object in that scenario means/what it will impact. My rule of thumb if it isn't obvious without looking at the code what the parameter does then it needs a better name and/or comments.

Comment: I would regard `Wack(Bozo bozoToBeWacked)` as an example of a redundancy in the variable name that is amply expressed by the method itself (and thus undesirable per the original question).  `Wack(Person bozo)` is more semantically valuable, however, as it implies that it is expected for only bozos to be wacked.

Comment: In the case you mention in the second paragraph, I will often rename the parameter to something like `initialRange`.  It is still very generic but doesn't have nearly the same level of distaste as `myRange`.

Comment: @Miral: It becomes more relevant in cases such as `Punch(Bozo punchingBozo, Bozo bozoToBePunched)`. Detailed naming is more relevant when you have to distinguish between multiple things (which are semantically described with pretty much the same words). OP's suggestion of `Range rangeToPad` is not necessary in his one parameter method example, but might be incredibly necessary for a method that takes in several  `Range` objects.

Comment: @Flater `Punch(Bozo source, Bozo target)` would do the job

Answer (score 16):

I do this all the time, it is giving me great piece of mind. If it is an argument passed to a constructor that needs to be assigned to a member, my member would be named range as well and the assignment would be

```
this.range = range;
```

And I would typically have a property named Range.

They are all the same thing, only differing in context so it makes sense to maintain a single name and you will have to remember only one name. It is one thing, the differences are purely technical.

You should be strict with fully qualifying members with "this." though, but that is what StyleCop is for.

**StyleCop side note**

Controversy guaranteed!

To those advocating against the use of "this.": I have seen _, m, m_ and just nothing. The language itself is offering us a perfectly clear, unambiguous universally recognizable way of indicating we are dealing with a class member. Why on earth would you want to make up your own way that mutilates already perfect names?

The only reason I can think of it that it is a legacy habit from the C era, when it actually made sense to do it because there was no other way.

"It is more characters!" Seriously? "Compile time will skyrocket!" Seriously? "I will have to lift my pinky when typing it!". As if typing time had any significance in the total development time.

I recognize that any style different from what you are used to will raise some opposition. But using this consistently is hard to argue with. Here's how it works for me: Before I push a new code file I run StyleCop and it will find a number of members lacking "this" qualifiers. I put "this." on the clipboard, run by the members and insert. No effort at all.

StyleCop does a lot more than this (haha). There are so many ways a developer can (only considering code formatting) frustrate the maintenance work of his successor. StyleCop prevents most of them. It is invaluable.

If you are new to it: it typically makes you grumble for a week or two and then you will love it.

Comment: "*You should be strict with fully qualifying members with "this." though,*" -1. Do not use `this` except when essential. It's just noise otherwise. Use `_range` for the field and `this` is never needed except in extension methods.

Comment: I concur with @DavidArno.  'this' is just pure noise. 'Range' is a property, '_range' is a field, and 'range' is a parameter.

Comment: @David  If the variable is a class member, it IS essential and beats any arbitrary prefix to signal you are looking at a class member rather than an argument or a local variable.

Comment: And seriously, what antiquated version of Visual Studio and C# are you using that you still use StyleCop? That doesn't even work with VS2015 and C# 6, which are positively ancient (VS2017.7 with C# 7.3 are currently in preview).

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ChrisDahlberg.StyleCop    Alive and kicking, continuing to protect us from the stylistic whims of the likes of you.

Comment: @MartinMaat, sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but the developers themselves admit it's dead: https://github.com/StyleCop/StyleCop. Time to move on... :)

Comment: @DavidArno, probably a better link: https://github.com/StyleCop/StyleCop/issues/73  Which points to the DotNetAnalyzers instance that uses Roslyn.  That said, I agree that relying on using the `this.` to get it right opens you to subtle bugs that you can spend hours tracking down.  I know from personal experience.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch, true, [StyleCopAnalyzers](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers) is the Roslyn-based rewrite. It still remains a bunch of crap rules though ;)

Comment: @17of26 How is using 'this' for properties any different than using '_' for fields?

Comment: Spot the bug: `public void setLabel(Lable lable){ lable = lable; lable.Text="Now you see mee";}`  Then put that in a class with hundreds of lines.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch Well, you're clearly missing an assignment to `this.label`, and `Lable` and `lable` are typos of `Label` and `label`. But then again, I'm used to Python where `self` (or `this`) is always explicit rather than implicit.

Comment: My IDE would shoot fireballs the second I would assign a variable to itself.

Comment: @DavidArno Care to explain why the "noise" of `_` is preferable over the noise of `this.`? I would argue one has meaning enforced by the language (and typically have syntax highlighting) while the other does not.

Comment: 'this.' slows down scanning/reading of code.  Your brain has to parse 'this.' before getting to the beginning of the specific member variable.  'this.foo' is two pieces of information, '_foo' is one.

Comment: @Clint What's easier to read?  'this.area = this.width * this.height;'  or '_area = _width * _height;'?  .  The first version has 46% more characters to provide the same information.

Comment: @17of26 In a comment on SE I would say the underscores are easier to read, but in and IDE I feel it's more of less the same. `_foo` has just as much information as `this.foo` and I'm not sure I buy the whole less characters is better argument. Is `_a = _w * _h` easier to read than your example? It's 60% less characters after all. My point is that I don't think that comment is worthy of a down vote. It doesn't really matter which method you use (if at all) as long as you're consistent. Personally, I only use `this.` when scope needs to be explicit (rarely) and never use `_` for fields.

Comment: Surely the main benefit of a prefix for class field members is that you then prevent any ambiguity between fields and method parameter names. Say in this case you had a class field named `range` without a prefix, and a method that took a parameter, also named `range`. You now have to spend extra mental effort wondering about which `range` is being referred to in the method. You also have to add `this.` as a prefix when referencing the field; not too bad when it's a simple type, but a lot of extra keystrokes when the supplied parameter is an object and several of its properties need to be set.

Comment: @Clint The point wasn't that the noise of `_` is better than the noise of `this.`, but that if the parameter name is different, `this` is unnecessary. My IDE actually gives a warning for that.

Comment: That being said, I prefer `_` for 2 reasons: 1) You only have to type one character to get a list of all private variables. 2) The speed and ease of writing a standard assignment. With the parameter name `ctrl-c`ed, go `_` `ctrl-v` `=` `ctrl-v` `;` - takes not more than half a second. Writing `this.` is more keys, but also the `s` makes me lift up my left hand from the ctrl-v position. It's a minor thing, but one that you'll do hundreds of times.

Comment: @17of26 You compare `_area = _width * _height` to `this.area = this.width * this.height`, but you should compare it to `area = width * height` instead as you don't need the prefix except when there's an equally named parameter - which is only the case in constructors. This style is grossly prevalent in Java.

Comment: @maaartinus, you miss the point: this answer is arguing that `this.` be used *everywhere*, not just in constructors. So `this.area = this.width * this.height` is a valid example of its noisiness.

Comment: Justifying the use of identical names for variables with "They are all the same value, only differing in context" seems completely back-to-front to me. The value has nothing to do with the naming of a variable, while context has everything to do with it.

Comment: @Andreas  Value is indeed not the appropriate word here, thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: @DavidArno You're right, I missed that. An idea: It's structured noise and the IDE could simply hide it and show highlighting instead. Typing is no problem, the IDE can do it easily (for Java, Eclipse has the commands "assign x to the field x" and "add missing 'this' qualifiers").

Comment: "*Why on earth would you want to make up your own way that mutilates already perfect names?*". [Because that "own way" is actually the standard adopted by the language developers](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/ExpressionEvaluator/CSharp/Source/ExpressionCompiler/CSharpEESymbolProvider.cs). If it's good enough for the C# language development team, it's certainly good enough for me and you. So why do you feel you should try to impose a different standard on folk?

Comment: @DavidArno You may find many examples of it being used, however [it goes against Microsoft's .NET naming guidelines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions). It's really not the standard for the framework and you shouldn't advertise it as such.

Comment: @Clint Hey nice find. I hadn’t appreciated they’d started porting those old guidelines over to the new community-editable docs. The beauty of that is that anyone can submit a PR to update those docs. Time to modernise them to reflect what folk really do these days. 

Comment: "*Here's how it works for me: Before I push a new code file I run StyleCop...*". Seriously, you need to modernise your workflow. Switch to VS2017 and add StyleCopAnalyzers to your projects via nuget, Those analyzers are effectively compiler extensions. This means they run *as you type*. So you get "red squigglies" appearing when you deviate from the rules and compilation errors when you build. The world has moved on. Even if you stick to your antiquated conventions, move to newer tools at least.

Comment: @DavidArno What you makes you think they're old? Everything I can find suggests that `_` *was* in the guidelines for private fields, but was removed. I will be interested to hear the outcome of your "modernizing" PR...

Comment: @Clint, the fact that the only folk I know who consider `this.` a good idea are still using VS2013 or older. And it will indeed be interesting to see what comes of my PR. :)

Comment: @David  I know all about the squigglies and FYI, I am using VS2017. But last time I tried, the NuGet package didn't work that well. There was something about turning on StyleCop for selected projects in a solution they screwed up or that would not persist over sessions, I don't remember exactly what the problem was. So we sticked to the on demand scanner for the time being. Doing so circumventing the performance hit for interactive builds, which is substantial in a moderately big solution.

Comment: @DavidArno I found [some information higher up in the doc tree](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines), "... required only to apply them to APIs that are publicly exposed (public or protected types and members, and explicitly implemented interfaces)." So really there is no set standard, which brings me back to being consistent (with your code and your teams) is more important than which method you decide to use.

Answer (score 9):

My self-guidance on naming methods, parameters and variables is pretty simple:

1. If the name contains the type that is being passed in or returned, you're doing it wrong.
2. Name things by what they are intended for, not what they are.
3. Always remember that code is read more than it is written.

Thus the optimal method signature, in my opinion, would be:

```
Range Pad(Range toPad)
```

Shortening the method name is self-explanatory.

The parameter name `toPad` immediately tells the reader that that parameter is probably going to be modified in-place by being padded, then returned. In contrast, no assumptions can be made about a variable named `range`.

Further, in the actual body of the method, any other `Range` variables that are introduced would (should) be named by their intent, so you might have `padded` and `unpadded`... `toPad` conforms to those naming conventions, but `range` just sticks out and doesn't gel.

Comment: `padded`/`unpadded` sounds good for local immutable variables. But if there is a mutable `toPad` parameter, then after the padding has been done the name `toPad` does not fit any more (unless the result is returned immediately). I would rather stick to `Range range` in those cases.

Comment: @Kapep I'd call it just `result`. It gets *modified* and *returned*. The latter is clear from the name and the former follows, as returning an unmodified argument makes no sense.

Comment: From the signature, the `Pad` method returns a `Range`.  That, to me, implies that the one I've passed in will be preserved, not modified in-place, and a new, padded `Range` will be returned.  .

Comment: I'm not sure what to think of your advice. `Pad(toPad)` feels kinda wrong IMHO. You make a good point of defending your point of view though. You get a +0 from me! :)

Comment: In the question it states that it "returns a new range that has had some padding applied". I agree with your naming for what you think the scenario is, but for the actual question I'd go for something like Range CreateRangeWithPadding(Range source)

Answer (score 3):

For naming of code elements (types, variables, functions, anything), the key question to ask yourself is

### If I make a typo, will the compiler find it for me?

The worst kind of typo-based bug is one where the code compiles and runs, but gives different behaviour from what you expect, for reasons which are subtle.  And since it's due to a typo, it's usually very hard to see when you're inspecting the code.  If a typo will stop the code compiling, then the compiler will flag up the line causing the problem, and you can easily find and fix it.

For your situation where the type and variable differ only in capitalisation, this will always be the case.  (Or nearly always - with sufficient effort, I'm sure you could make it work, but you'd have to really try.)  So I think you're OK there.

Where you would need to be concerned would be if there were two variables, methods, functions or properties in current scope called `range` and `Range`.  In that case the compiler probably *will* let it through, and you're going to get unexpected behaviour at run-time.  Note that that's two of *any* of those types of code element, not just "two variables" or "two functions" - all of those can be implicitly cast to each other, with resulting carnage when it runs.  You might get warnings, but you can't guarantee anything more than that.  You have similar issues if you had two types declared called `range` and `Range`.

Also note the same applies to the [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) style, where names are prefixed with one or more characters to say something more about whatever it is.  If you have a variable called `Range` and a pointer to it called `PRange`, it's easy to accidentally miss the `P`, for example.  C# should catch this, but C and C++ will only give you a warning at most.  Or more worryingly, suppose you have an double version called `DRange` and you downsample that to a float version called `FRange`.  Use the float one by accident (which is easy since the keys are adjacent on a keyboard) and your code will *kind of* work, but it'll fall over in strange and unpredictable ways when the process runs out of resolution and underflows.

We're no longer in the days where we had naming limits of 8 characters, or 16 characters, or whatever arbitrary limit.  I've sometimes heard novices complaining about longer variable names making coding take longer.  It's only ever novices who complain about this though.  Serious coders know that what *really* takes time is figuring out obscure bugs - and bad choice of naming is a classic way to drop yourself in that particular hole.

Comment: Just a note for the readers - for C#, people should _really_ avoid Hungarian Notation. While it was useful in older times when syntax highlight wasn't a thing or was limited, nowadays it really doesn't help.

Comment: @T.Sar Even back in the day, I hated it with a passion!  As you say, better IDEs have solved the problems it was aimed at, but it still appears every so often.  You'll still see it if you need to talk to the Windows API, for instance, for historical reasons. I didn't want to totally bash people's preferred styles if they really like it, but I did want to use it as a hook for showing that upper/lower case isn't the only way you can screw up naming.

Comment: I'm aware that you're not proposing the use of Hungarian Notation, but I'm also aware that young devs have a enormous weakness for things with cool names. Being able to say "My code is written in this super secret ninja coding style - the Hungarian Notation!" may sound irresistibly cool to the younger minds. I've seen too many devs fall prey to the hype of cool words...
Hungarian Notation is pain give the form of source code x.X

Comment: @T.Sar True enough.  "Those who do not remember the past are doomed to repeat it" and all that. :/

Comment: Are we talking about the original Hungarian notation or [how it was grossly misinterpreted by Microsoft](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/) (near *"the documentation writers on the Windows team inadvertently invented what came to be known as Systems Hungarian"* and also [in interview of Joel Spolsky by Leo Laporte on Triangulation episode 277, 2016-12-12, 04 mins 00 secs - 06 mins 35 secs](https://twit.tv/shows/triangulation/episodes/277))?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Any flavour of it. I can appreciate why it was needed for BCPL, and in a time without good IDEs, but 40 years later it's just inappropriate. But I wanted to use it as an example of how a bad choice of names (and in that case, one which would be enforced by the coding standard) can leave you vulnerable to bugs from easy-to-make typos. The message wasn't "Hungarian notation considered harmful" (which is just an opinion), it was "typo vulnerability considered harmful" (which is evidence-based best practice).

Comment: @Graham I take it from your objection to "any flavour of" Hungarian notation, that you have not read [Joel Spolsky's article on the usefulness of genuine Hungarian notation](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/)

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I've read it, but he's simply wrong - or more accurately, he was writing from a position which was kind-of valid 20 years ago but isn't now. (Even in 2005, IDEs were smart enough to sort this.) Helping the coder's eyeballs spot the problem is wrong, as shown by all safety-related coding standards, which all insist on static analysis because coders' eyeballs are *not* as reliable as Joel thought. Letting your compiler and static analysis tools find these bugs for you will *always* be better (and that's an evidence-based statement from MISRA and from the authors of DO-178B).

Answer (score 1):

One anecdote I would like to add, while `Range range` this is syntactically legal, it could make things more challenging to debug or refactor. Looking for that one variable named "range" in a file with lots of variables of type Range? You may end up doing more work later as a result of this naming choice.

This is largely context-dependent though. If it is a 30 line file, my statements don't really come into play.

Comment: Most people use tools that distinguish between types and parameters or variables, for Windows development. What you describe reminds me of the good old grep days on Unix.

Comment: @FrankHileman It might surprise you, but Unix is still alive and grep is still in use (:D). As grep is by default case-sensitive, the mentioned problem just doesn't exist. However, even we, terminal-addicted windows-haters, rarely use grep for source code as the IDE is much better at common searches.

Comment: I think that we agree that the platform is not the point. `grep` is a great tool, but it is not a refactoring tool. And refactoring tools exist on every development platform I've used. (OS X, Ubuntu, Windows).

Comment: @EricWilson At one time, grep and sed were the only refactoring tools on unix.

Comment: @FrankHileman Just because something is used as a refactoring tool doesn't mean it is one. I can refactor in notepad, but that doesn't make it more than a text editor.

Comment: @EricWilson Right. I started unix development on a Sun 1, when we had no symbolic debugger either. Things were a little different.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `Range range` nowdays for one reason: syntax highlighting. **Modern IDEs usually highlight the type names and the parameter names in different colors**. Also a type and a variable have a considerable "logical distance" not to be easily confused.

If this wouldn't be the case I would consider a different name or trying to enable a plugin/extension that can do this syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

When a function is generic, it stands to reason that the parameters will be generic, and thus should have generic names.

Not what you're saying, but I've seen functions that perform a generic function that have parameter names that are misleadingly specific. Like

```
public String removeNonDigits(String phoneNumber)
```

The function name sounds very generic, like this could be applied to many strings in many situations. But the parameter name is oddly specific, making me wonder if the function name is misleading, or ... what?

So sure, instead of saying Range range, you could say Range rangeToPad. But what information does this add? Of course it's the range to pad. What else would it be?

Adding some arbitrary prefix, "my" or "m_" or whatever, conveys zero additional information to the reader. When I've used languages where the compiler does not allow a variable name to be the same as a type name -- with or without case sensitivity -- I've sometimes put on a prefix or a suffix, just to get it to compile. But that's just to satisfy the compiler. One could argue that even if the compiler can distinguish, this makes it easier for a human reader to distinguish. But wow, in Java I've written statements like "Customer customer = new Customer();" a billion times and I never found it confusing. (I've always found it a bit redundant and I rather like that in VB you can just say "dim customer as new Customer" and you don't have to give the class name twice.)

Where I DO object strongly to generic names is when there are two or more instances of the same type in the same function. ESPECIALLY parameters. Like:

```
public Range pad(Range range1, Range range2)
```

What's the difference between range1 and range2? How am I supposed to know? If it's something where they truly are two generic and interchangeable values, okay, like

```
public boolean overlap(Range range1, Range range2)
```

I'd expect that to return true if the ranges overlap and false if they don't, so they are generic and interchangeable.

But if they're different, give me a clue how they are different! I was just working on a program recently that had a "Place" class to hold data about geographical places, and with variables of this type named "p", "place", "place2", "myPlace", etc. Wow, those names really help me determine which is which.